# How to draw square shaped dependent voltage and current sources in CircuiTikZ?

Tags: circuitikz

I would like to create square-shaped dependent voltage and current sources like in this figure. I would prefer to still be able to use them as options of the "to" command like this:

```
(0,0) to[SQvsource, l=$stuff$] ++(2,0)
```

[image]

Comment: Did you saw the answer? Any though?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to see how we can do it. Let's for example start with the voltage generator. The more similar object in the manual is clearly this:

[image]

The `nodename` without `shape` is how the bipoles are defined. Bipoles are defined in `pgfcircbipoles.tex`, so let's search for it:

```bash
% kpsewhere pgfcircbipoles.tex
/home/romano/texlive2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/circuitikz/pgfcircbipoles.tex
```

I will open it and search all the things related to our `cvsourceAM` and put them in test file among `\makeatletter`...`other` guards.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\makeatletter
\ctikzset{bipoles/cvsourceam/height/.initial=.7}
\ctikzset{bipoles/cvsourceam/width/.initial=.7}
\ctikzset{bipoles/cvsourceam/margin/.initial=.7}
\ctikzset{bipoles/cvsourceam/text scale/.initial=1}
%% To change the internal symbols of the controlled voltage source american style
\ctikzset{bipoles/cvsourceam/inner plus/.initial={$+$}}
\ctikzset{bipoles/cvsourceam/inner minus/.initial={$-$}}
%% Controlled voltage source - American
\pgfcircdeclarebipolescaled{csources}
{}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsourceam/height}}
{cvsourceAM}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsourceam/height}}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsourceam/width}}
{
    \pgf@circ@setlinewidth{bipoles}{\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@zero}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@zero}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@zero}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@zero}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgf@circ@draworfill

    \pgfsetcolor{\ctikzvalof{color}}
    \ifpgf@circ@oldvoltagedirection
        \pgftext[bottom,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@left]{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsourceam/inner plus}}
        \pgftext[top,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@right]{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsourceam/inner minus}}
    \else
        \pgftext[bottom,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@left]{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsourceam/inner minus}}
        \pgftext[top,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@right]{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsourceam/inner plus}}
    \fi
}
\pgfcirc@activate@bipole@opt{v}{cvsourceam}{cvsourceAM}{american controlled voltage source}{%
    \circuitikzbasekey/bipole/is voltage=true,
    \circuitikzbasekey/bipole/is voltageoutsideofsymbol=false}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[american]
    \draw (0,0) to[american controlled voltage source] ++(0,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

...nothing has changed, clearly, but check if it still compiles.

[image]

The code for the sources is a bit more complete than needed (and there is a capitalization bug there that I did not fix for fear of backward compatibility), but basically is quite straightforward.

Now I will change the name to our new component. Just globally replace it...

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\makeatletter
\ctikzset{bipoles/cvsquaream/height/.initial=.7}
\ctikzset{bipoles/cvsquaream/width/.initial=.7}
\ctikzset{bipoles/cvsquaream/margin/.initial=.7}
\ctikzset{bipoles/cvsquaream/text scale/.initial=1}
%% To change the internal symbols of the controlled voltage source american style
\ctikzset{bipoles/cvsquaream/inner plus/.initial={$+$}}
\ctikzset{bipoles/cvsquaream/inner minus/.initial={$-$}}
%% Controlled voltage source - American
\pgfcircdeclarebipolescaled{csources}
{}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsquaream/height}}
{cvsquaream}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsquaream/height}}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsquaream/width}}
{
    \pgf@circ@setlinewidth{bipoles}{\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@zero}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@zero}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@zero}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@zero}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgf@circ@draworfill

    \pgfsetcolor{\ctikzvalof{color}}
    \ifpgf@circ@oldvoltagedirection
        \pgftext[bottom,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsquaream/margin}\pgf@circ@res@left]{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsquaream/inner plus}}
        \pgftext[top,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsquaream/margin}\pgf@circ@res@right]{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsquaream/inner minus}}
    \else
        \pgftext[bottom,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsquaream/margin}\pgf@circ@res@left]{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsquaream/inner minus}}
        \pgftext[top,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsquaream/margin}\pgf@circ@res@right]{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsquaream/inner plus}}
    \fi
}
\pgfcirc@activate@bipole@opt{v}{cvsquaream}{cvsquaream}{SQvsource}{%
    \circuitikzbasekey/bipole/is voltage=true,
    \circuitikzbasekey/bipole/is voltageoutsideofsymbol=false}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[american]
    \draw (0,0) to[SQvsource] ++(0,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Notice the last line --- I have defined as the "alias" name of the new component `SQvsource` as you suggested. Now we must change the definition to draw what we want... the external diamond is drawn by

```latex
 \pgf@circ@setlinewidth{bipoles}{\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@zero}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@zero}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@zero}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@zero}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgf@circ@draworfill
```

so let's change it into, for example:

```latex
\pgf@circ@setlinewidth{bipoles}{\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
        {\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgf@circ@draworfill
```

and *voilà*:

[image]

...and everything will work as expected. The final circuit could be something like that:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\makeatletter
\ctikzset{bipoles/cvsquaream/height/.initial=.7}
\ctikzset{bipoles/cvsquaream/width/.initial=.7}
\ctikzset{bipoles/cvsquaream/margin/.initial=.7}
\ctikzset{bipoles/cvsquaream/text scale/.initial=1}
%% To change the internal symbols of the controlled voltage source american style
\ctikzset{bipoles/cvsquaream/inner plus/.initial={$+$}}
\ctikzset{bipoles/cvsquaream/inner minus/.initial={$-$}}
%% Controlled voltage source - American
\pgfcircdeclarebipolescaled{csources}
{}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsquaream/height}}
{cvsquaream}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsquaream/height}}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsquaream/width}}
{
    \pgf@circ@setlinewidth{bipoles}{\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
        {\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgf@circ@draworfill

    \pgfsetcolor{\ctikzvalof{color}}
    \ifpgf@circ@oldvoltagedirection
        \pgftext[bottom,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsquaream/margin}\pgf@circ@res@left]{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsquaream/inner plus}}
        \pgftext[top,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsquaream/margin}\pgf@circ@res@right]{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsquaream/inner minus}}
    \else
        \pgftext[bottom,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsquaream/margin}\pgf@circ@res@left]{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsquaream/inner minus}}
        \pgftext[top,rotate=90,y=\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsquaream/margin}\pgf@circ@res@right]{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/cvsquaream/inner plus}}
    \fi
}
\pgfcirc@activate@bipole@opt{v}{cvsquaream}{cvsquaream}{SQvsource}{%
    \circuitikzbasekey/bipole/is voltage=true,
    \circuitikzbasekey/bipole/is voltageoutsideofsymbol=false}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[american]
    \draw (0,0) -- ++(-2,0) to[SQvsource=$\nu_{sl}(t)$] ++(0,2) 
        to[short, i_=$i_{sl}(t)$] ++(2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The current generator is left as an exercise to the proficient reader ;-) (it shows I am a teacher, eh? `:-P`)